# Handling updating of data with "has many" relationships in web applications

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

So I have a situation that has arisen a few times in web applications I'm building. I feel like there has to be a better way to handle this, so I'll detail my current technique and hopefully some of you far more experienced developers can suggest better options.

Essentially the issue revolves around editing data with multiple relationships in an app that uses a Relational Database for the data storage (particularly, I often use MySQL).

So let's imagine this database schema (although it could be any similar set-up):

User has many Skill
Skill belongs to User

When I create a new user, I'll fill out their basic info as well as some (or none at all) skills. When I click save, my app will take this data and save a new user alongside zero, one or many skill entries in the database.

Now, when I go to edit this user a form will display showing the user's basic info, and multiple fields for each skill. I may choose to remove skills, add new skills or both.

Currently I handle this by removing the fields using Javascript and I add new skill fields using Javascript as well. I'd like to not immediately delete a skill from the database when "remove" is clicked, but rather just remove the field and then delete the field once the user submits the form.

In my server side code, usually I would handle this by deleting all previous skill entries for this user and then save all POSTed in skill entries. The other option is to only delete skill entries that are not in the POSTed in skill entry IDs, then update the records for each one that was POSTed in.

Does this seem like a good way to handle this? Is there a better way to manage this? I'm open to any suggestion even if the process differs significantly from what I'm doing now.

For further reference, I'm doing this in a PHP and MySQL app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to rewrite all the Skills fields every time you get the data. All the process would take 1 query to go (just update query).

If you will delete non-POST'ed Skills you will have to do lot of comparison.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. If I remove a couple of skills, then add a couple, then edit a couple as well, I end up with some skill records that need to be created and some that need to be deleted and some that need to be updated. With a deletion of all records then saving of all new ones, I feel it's much easier. But there must be alternatives.